# How to edit css for jquery datepicker prev/next buttons?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Using the JQuery UI datepicker, in the header it gives you the option to go to the next month or previous month with left/right arrows. My question is what is the css property to change the colors when hovering over the previous or next arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little harder than it seems.  As NimChipsky pointed out, it's in ui-state-hover, but the colors aren't there directly.

If you look at ui-state-hover, out of the box, you will see something that looks like:

```
background-image: url("images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png");
```

Basically, this is telling you that you will be using an icon sheet with color #222222, but the icon sheet graphic has to be available.  You can generate other icon sheets directly, with other colors, by using the jQuery UI theme builder.

Answer (score 1):

`ui-state-hover` is the class that is applied when hovering, see [here](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(".ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        });
</script>
```

and css for your class 'hover'

```
.hover
{
    background-image:url('paper.gif');
}
```