# datepicker css color for NEXT and PREV

Tags: datepicker

sorry for the NOOB question, but the pop-up calendar I am getting has a gray header with date in it, the `next` and `prev` buttons ended up being the same color as the header and thus are hidden? they stil work but are not visible, I trying to change the color of the triangle using css but can't seem to grt it:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e span {
color: black;
}
```

this is my attempt?

I'm not opposed to changing the header color if that is easier, I have looked at several SO solutions like: [How to edit css for jquery datepicker prev/next buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508779/how-to-edit-css-for-jquery-datepicker-prev-next-buttons)

but not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those icons are generated using a PNG file. You probably using downloaded Jquery UI css not the CDN. When you download the Jquery UI zip folder it contains the images too. Copy them to your folder.